# Get the imported classes' name of a class

Tags: java

now I have a class looks like following:

```
package a.b.c;

import java.util.List;

public class FactObject {
    private double a;
    private double b;
    private List<String> c;
}
```

I know I could get the package name of this class by doing:

```
FactObject fo = new FactObject();
Class<?> c = fo.getClass();
String packageName = c.getPackage().getName();
```

But how can I get the imported class string, in this case, "java.util.List" ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `import` statements are only relevant at compilation time. If you want to get the type of the field, use reflection.

Comment: What is the use case for which you need the import class name?

Comment: @VishalKamat Because I need to record all the necessary information of a class into a string. This string will be used in our rules engine.

Answer (score 1):

As you already use the class name directly in your code, the answer is given by `FactObject.class.getName()`.